# How to start, where to learn ( Farseer )

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, farseer

Last few days I'm trying to start with farseer library, however i just can't get anything work properly. Documentation is very poor and there aren't many ( any? ) resources on the internet relating to 3.3.1 version. It's my first time trying to use physics engine, so it is even bigger problem to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are examples in their [tutorial section](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tutorials&referringTitle=Home) as well as their [sample](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/88395#1641914) source code. In particular, if you want to see how a certain function can be used, you should go through their [Test Bed](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/88395#1436606) source code which demonstrates how to the use main functions in XNA.

For theory, and possibly other methods, you can look for documentations related to [Box2D](http://www.box2d.org/). Farseer is a port of the Box2D engine, so most information from Box2D can be transferred to Farseer quite easily.

Comment: I can find only 3.3.1 on codeplex download site, is there any other place i should get it from?

Comment: I might be blind, or just too exhausted, but i still see only 3.3, 3.2 or 3.3.1, not 3.3.3 :)

Comment: @Neomex - My bad, I'm the one being blind :D. `3.3.1` is the latest one :) Apologies for that goose chase.

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a bit documentation...

http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/documentation

This is where you would start.

Comment: Yes, i checked it before, but I'd rather say that it is some kind of small introduction, not real manual.

Answer (score 1):

You should study the simple [examples project](http://farseersimplesamples.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex in order to get started. The next step is to get involved on the codeplex forum and the StackOverflow tag.

Comment: sad thing that most of them are for older version, but it helps me anyway, thanks

Comment: Yeah i was hoping for an update by now. I went through all of these last fall.